# how to change wpf datepicker culture?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I have a `WPF application on the dotnet core 7` platform and in the `App class`, in the `OnStartup` event, I have changed the Culture as follows: When I use `DatePicker`, when I click on the `date selection button`, it shows me the Persian calendar correctly. However, when I select a date, it displays the Gregorian date in Persian numbers. When I click on the year at the top of the page to select the date, it shows me the Gregorian months in Persian. Then, when I click again, it shows me the Gregorian years. What should I do to solve this problem? I have attached a sample image of the program running.

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

    FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
}
```

---

```
...
<StackPanel FlowDirection="RightToLeft" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,10,0" Height="209">
    <DatePicker />
...
```

[image: show image of problem]

Comment: Do you mean why show months and years like a translator and not show Jalali Equivalent on the interface?

Comment: Yes i want it shows jalali month, year and date when picked @MRAlam

Comment: in the last line you refer to *CultureInfo.CurrentCulture*, in the lines before you set *Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture*. Depending on .NET version and OS this is not always the same. Maybe in the last line ùse your fa-IR variable aswell:  `XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(currentInfo.IetfLanguageTag)));`

Answer (score 0):

i think the default DatePicker don't do it, CultureInfo in C# is primarily designed to provide information about various cultural aspects such as language, currency, date and time formatting, and more. However, it doesn't inherently provide support for converting between different calendar systems, such as the Gregorian calendar and the Jalali (Persian) calendar.

for doing this you need to use one component, that support Jalali calendar. there are a lot of in the internet like :
[this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PersianCalendarWPF)

or i think you can change the default month name manually after checked CultureInfo Values something like :

```
if (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name == "fa-IR")
        {
            // Create a custom DateTimeFormatInfo with Persian month names
            DateTimeFormatInfo customFormat = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
            customFormat.MonthNames = new string[]
            {
                "فروردین", "اردیبهشت", "خرداد",
                "تیر", "مرداد", "شهریور",
                "مهر", "آبان", "آذر",
                "دی", "بهمن", "اسفند"
            };

            // Set the custom DateTimeFormatInfo as the format for the DatePicker
            datePicker.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag);
            datePicker.LanguageSpecificResources = customFormat;
}
```